# How make correct Mysql Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a two tables.

One is "**detailtousers**" contains information about the users and any "**commenttousers**" contains info about comments.

Dump by table **detailtousers**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `detailtousers` (
  `idDetailToUsers` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DetailToUsersName` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `DetailToUsersEmail` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DetailToUsersPhone` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DetailToUsersExpirience` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `DetailToUsersCity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DetailToUsersCountry` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DetailToUsersSite` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DetailToUsersAge` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DetailToUsersSex` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DetailToUsersPhoto` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DetailToUsersToMF` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DetailToUsersFB` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DetailToUsersTW` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DetailToUsersYTB` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DetailToUsersVIP` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `DetailToUsersPalata` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DetailToUsersHide` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDetailToUsers`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idDetailToUsers_UNIQUE` (`idDetailToUsers`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Dump by table: **commenttousers**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `commenttousers` (
  `idCommentToUsers` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CommentToUsersTime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CommentToUsersIdUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CommentToUsersComment` text NOT NULL,
  `CommentToUsersStatus` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CommentToUsersIdToUser` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCommentToUsers`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idCommentToUsers_UNIQUE` (`idCommentToUsers`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

I want select all comments AND get fields:  *DetailToUsersName*, *CommentToUsersComment*, *CommentToUsersIdToUser*, *CommentToUsersIdUser*, C*ommentToUsersTime*.

Note, please to field **CommentToUsersIdUser**, **CommentToUsersIdToUser**
From field CommentToUsersIdToUser i want get Name of user Who was left for comment and i must make connect the table again.

Now I'm trying to do so:

```
SELECT `*s` FROM (`commenttousers`) LEFT JOIN `detailtousers` ON `detailtousers`.`idDetailToUsers` = `commenttousers`.`CommentToUsersIdToUser` LIMIT 5
```

So, it gives me that i need, but i can not get info about which user was left a comment. (her Name from table **detailtousers**)
Can you help me find resolve, please.

Comment: Can you explain me, why my post gave -1 point? Who is here a very clever? I asked the question seems to be correctly

Comment: Out of curiosity what kind of information do you store at `DetailToUsersName` or `DetailToUsersEmail` for example ? Or is `DetailToUsersName` simple the actual `username` ?

Comment: Haven't read your question but your title is pretty lame. I am tempted to -1 also. It doesn't say anything, yet suggests the question will be lame as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should again join with `detailtousers` table to get the both user details.

```
SELECT a.*, /*select necessary fields from comments*/
b.DetailToUsersName, /*select necessary details about users*/
c.DetailToUsersName /*select necessary details about users*/
  FROM commenttousers a
       INNER JOIN detailtousers b
          ON b.idDetailToUsers = a.CommentToUsersIdToUser
       INNER JOIN detailtousers c
          ON c.idDetailToUsers = a.CommentToUsersIdUser
 LIMIT 5;
```